# How do I determine a good function to fit a set of data?

Tags: curves, data-analysis

I have a calculated some rates based on data, but I was wondering if there is a way to determine a good math function that might fit this data. For example, consider the following:

```
0.1387 
0.3840 
0.2744 
0.1654 
0.1062 
0.0748 
0.0502 
0.0397 
0.0342 
0.0268 
0.0204 
0.0089 
0.0064 
0.0102 
0.0092 
0.0064 
0.0039 
0.0036
```

This looks like the following: [image: Graphical representation].

I tried a polynomial function, but that (perhaps obviously) doesn't work. I also tried the poisson function, but the fit did not appear to be very good. So I'm wondering how I go about thinking what function might be better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does your data set come from? That may give you some good *a priori* ideas.

Comment: If you ignore the first value, the shape looks like inverse proportionality. Is it allowed?

Comment: Is the jump on the few 1st data important? If not, this looks like hyperbola.

Comment: Did you try a function like $f : x\mapsto ae^{-bx}$? To find the coefficients, a linear regression of $\ln y$ with respect to $x$ could help since $y = ae^{-bx}\iff \ln y = \ln (a) - bx$. Of course, you won't have the first point.

Comment: Do the $x$ coordinates go up in 1?

Comment: Try  $ f(x) = ax^{\alpha}e^{-\beta x}$  with different parameters to find a good match.

Comment: One thing you can do to see how well an exponential tail fits is to plot log(y) vs x and see if it looks like a straight line. To see how well it resembles a hyperbola, plot y vs 1/x and see if it resembles a straight line. To see if it’s power law decay more generally, plot log(y) vs log(x) and see if it resembles a straight line

Comment: @Mohammad you realize the “hump” part is one data point, right?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen somehow  we have to address the hump. What do you suggest?

Comment: Also, it’s strange that your x axis is unlabeled, is it something like uniformly spaced time samples where it makes sense to look at a trend?

Comment: @mohammad I am suggesting not addressing the hump until we know more about it e.g. whether it’s real or important. (And if so, getting more data on it if possible.)

Comment: (Oh silly me, I see you simply did not give us the x data... there clearly aren’t sixty something data points... though I’m not sure why you thought the y data would be helpful without it.)

Comment: Sorry I've ignored all these questions/advice. The data represents monthly win rates on sales deals. So after a contract goes out a few wins come in the same month as the contract, most come in the next month, and then they taper off from there. Sorry this was not clear. Regarding the x data, it is simply 0 .. 17 (i.e., first 1.5yrs after a contract being sent including the month it was sent). The hump is real and is based on aggregated data (simply represented as one point). I have tried the approach suggested by @Mohammad and it works nicely. I will post as an answer for posterity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the feedback and helpful advice received above, I did the following (leverages python to figure out parameter estimates):

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.misc import factorial
from scipy.optimize import minimize
xs = np.arange(18)
ys = np.array([
    0.1387,
    0.3840,
    0.2744,
    0.1654,
    0.1062,
    0.0748,
    0.0502,
    0.0397,
    0.0342,
    0.0268,
    0.0204,
    0.0089,
    0.0064,
    0.0102,
    0.0092,
    0.0064,
    0.0039,
    0.0036,
])
plt.plot(xs, ys, ls='-', marker='o', markersize=4, markerfacecolor='#FFFFFF', label='Actual')
fn = lambda x, a, α, β, b, θ: a * x ** α * np.exp(-β * x) + θ * (1 - (x / (abs(x - 1) + 1))) # second
fit_params, pcov = curve_fit(fn, xs, ys)
y_new = fn(xs, *fit_params)
plt.plot(xs, y_new, ls='-', marker='o', markersize=4, markerfacecolor='#FFFFFF', label='Model')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The results seem promising:
[image]

Thanks for the help!